# How postgres access tables on disc

Tags: postgresql

I am having a postgres table with 2 columns username and items they have bought. On an average we could expect about 100 items for each user. While thinking about this, I am wondering the possible issues I could face if I plan to have a unique table corresponding to each user rather than having a single table storing data of all the items bought by all the users.

One thing I realised was, since postgres stores data in chunks of 8kB I'll be consuming lot of disc space than required (as I will certainly not have 8kB of data for any specific user). But, will this help me to reduce time to fetch the items corresponding to a given user as I could directly fetch all the rows from the table of that specific user compared to searching for the rows corresponding to a given user (if I plan to save all the data in a single table) and then return the items?

Comment: Anything but one (perhaps partitioned) table for all users would be madness.

Comment: You seem to be thinking one block can only hold one row.  That is not so.

Comment: Hi @jjanes, I am trying to say I'll have multiple rows but total data in each of the user's table will be nowhere near 8kB

Comment: Ah, I see.  Each row has considerable overhead.  100 rows might not take up 8k, but it won't be drastically less than that amount.  But having thousands or millions of tiny tables is probably a bad idea anyway.  Just have the right indexes.